# Taylor's Series problem

Tags: calculus

Hello I have a problem that I want to solve because it is bugging me a lot. I have this problem in my calculus class, and this is a problem that will be presented by the teacher tomorrow.

$$a e^x + \sqrt{1-b^2 x^2} + c = 1 + 10x + 3x^2 + o(x^2)$$

What is $a, b, c$ ?

I'm really confused about how you solve $a, b, c$, and is it even possible? Is there something that I don't know? Please enlighten me!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the Taylor series for the left hand side?

Comment: the first few terms of $\sqrt{1-t} $ are $1 - t/2 - t^2/8 - t^3/16$ and you just plug in $t=bx$ for that piece of the question

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but my problem is the o(x^2)

Comment: $o(x^2)$ just means, in this case anyways, "the terms of higher power than $x^2$".

Comment: That is the form of the complementary term in Taylor-Young's formula. This veing sai,iin the expansion of \sqrt'1-b^2x^2}, you should substitute $b^2x^2$ to $t$, so that you only need an expansion at order $1$.

Comment: I think I solved it. The 3 equation I was given by approximating the left side and then equaling it to the right side was:  c+a+1 = 1, a*x = 10x (ax^2-b^2 * x^2) /2 = 6x^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are searching for the Taylor's expansion at $x=0$, you can use that
$$
ae^x=a+ax+\frac{ax^2}{2}+o\left(x^2\right)
$$
$$
\sqrt{1-b^2x^2}=1-\frac{b^2x^2}{2}+o\left(x^2\right)
$$

You can deduce from this a taylor expansion of order 2 that you can compare to the one that's given.

Comment: the denominator for $b^2 x^2$ should be 2

Comment: Yes, and the equation that I am getting are: 
c+a+1 = 1,
a*x = 10x
(ax^2-b^2 * x^2) /2 = 6x^2
and therefore I can solve the equation. I finally understand. Thank you.

Comment: @WillJagy Youps, sorry i correct it. Pls see the correction Student of math, sorry for the little mistake

Comment: It's okay, thanks for helping :P